# After ng build css background changed in angular 6.x

Tags: angular, ng-build

1. angular.json

[image: 1]

2. in my login.component.ts

[image: 2]

3. in my dist folder

[image: 3]

4. in dist folder main.js some png setting code

[image: 4]

5. angular-cli 6.2.6 node 8.9.0 ant-design

after ng build ... some pictures which are in assets/ now is in dist root folder and background-url changed please help me